# SSH to RPi via PuTTY giving "Network Error: Connection Refused"

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, putty

I cannot SSH to my RPi because of this error. I am trying port 22 by default.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

SSh is disabled by default on *all* [new raspbian installs.](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/a-security-update-for-raspbian-pixel/) To enable it you will either need to physically log in and enable it with `sudo raspi-config` or insert your sd card into another computer and create a file called `ssh` with no filename extension to enable it on the boot partition. Then make sure it's connected to WI-FI and try again.

Comment: so my next question is what is the boot partition?? i.e. where do i save this ssh file?

Comment: Thanks. Very bad idea to have SSH disabled by default... :(

Comment: Look under item 5 "Interfacing Options"